# Update SQL with a null or int value

Tags: c#, sql, null

I want to be able to update the table from c# with either a null or int.  The dropdown will either have an id as the selected value or empty string, if it's an empty string I want to pass a null otherwise I want the id. I've tried this but getting an error "Input string was not in a correct format." Can anyone help? Thanks

```
  var result = (from p in dc.Prices where p.price_ID == Id select p).FirstOrDefault();

  result.no_update = String.IsNullOrEmpty((grd.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("ddlNoUpdate") as DropDownList).SelectedValue.ToString()) ? System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt32.Null.Value : int.Parse((grd.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("ddlNoUpdate") as DropDownList).SelectedValue.ToString());

  dc.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: Have you tried just setting it to "null", and is no_update of nullable  type?

Comment: I'm guessing SelectedValue is set incorrectly and it's not a Null/Empty String OR integer, instead it is another value.  Put up a full code sample and we can help...

Comment: Check what you have in SelectedValue, it seems it's failing when you try to convert it to int

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

Try using this code, it worked for me once

```
String insertedVal = (grd.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("ddlNoUpdate") as DropDownList).SelectedValue.ToString()

result.no_update = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(insertedVal)
    ? (object)DBNull.Value : (object)insertedVal
```